# Проверка границ в управляемом и неуправляемом коде

Tags: c#

1) Как принудительно включить проверку границ в управляемом и неуправляемом коде?

2) Как отловить такие ошибки?

Например для неуправляемого кода в том же дельфи есть опция Range Check Errors, для отлова таких ошибок.

Что в этом плане нам может предложить шарп?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Range Check Errors в дельфи - это две раздельных фичи в C#/.NET

Первая - это проверка на arithmetic overflow / underflow. Включается в свойствах проекта, в Build / Advanced.

Эта проверка действует только в пределах checked-регионов. Т.е. она 
- будет работать по умолчанию, 
- не будет работать внутри региона `unchecked { код }` 
- будет работать внутри региона `checked { код }` вложенонго в `unchecked`

Указатели и fixed-size буфферы можно использовать только внутри `unchecked`-регионов, так что в принципе можно сказать что проверка работает только для управляемого кода.

Кроме того, опция arithmetic overflow / underflow - это аттрибут сборки. Т.е. включить ли проверку для кода внутри конкретной DLL определяется на этапе ее компиляции. Выставление это опции заставляет компилятор C# заменять команды IL для работы с числами - `add`, `mul` - на их аналоги, проверяющие overflow - `add.ovf`, `mul.ovf`.

Если сборка уже готова и вы ее просто используете - то изменить настройку для кода внутри ее не получится.

---

Вторая - это проверка на выход за границы массива, и для управляемого кода ее отключить нельзя.

В неуправляемом коде ее наоборот, нельзя включить. Просто потому, что в терминах неуправляемого кода массивов как таковых нет. Есть указатели. Есть функции работы с памятью. А массивов как цельных объектов - куска памяти + длины - нет.

В дельфи Range Check Errors работает только с внутренними паскальными массивами - которые на самом деле вполне управляемые - среда выполнения знает об их длине.

Comment: "Проверка на выход за границы массива, и для управляемого кода ее отключить нельзя. " - не совсем так. JIT в следствии оптимизаций может самостоятельно отключить эту проверку. Так же интересует как запретить JIT отключать проверку на выход за границу массива.

Comment: @z668 не может. а если может - приведите пример.

Comment: http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/optimization/level7/7_6.php почитайте со строк "Отключение проверки границ".

Comment: @z668 я читал http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/08/13/array-bounds-check-elimination-in-the-clr.aspx - там очень подробно расписано, почему в каждом случае проверку можно **безопасно** убрать. вы хотите чтобы jit делал проверки даже тогда, когда они заведомо излишни?

Comment: Да, мне нужно для отладки чтобы проверка границ была всегда включена хотябы для управляемого кода, раз для неуправляемого ее вклчить нельзя. Это возможно?

Comment: @z668 jit не отключает проверку. он убирает *излишние* проверки в машинном коде, которые заведомо дадут ложный результат. т.е. вы все равно не сможете написать такой управляемый код, который обратился бы за пределы массива в обход проверке.  это оптимизация из той же категории что и "заменить `true == true` на `true`", или выбросить код в ветке `if (false) { some code }`, или "заинлайнить метод"

Comment: Еще хотел бы прояснить для себя несколько моментов. Опция "arithmetic overflow / underflow" работает только для управляемого кода? Как быть если есть приложение, которое грузит в отдельный AddDomain сборку (управляемую .dll, которая содержит часть неуправляемого кода), и исключение происходит в ней. У меня русская студия. Должны ли стоять опции "Включить анализ кода в сборке" и "Разрешить отладку машинного кода"? Так же как будут взаимодействовать эти опции совместно с включенной "arithmetic overflow / underflow". Могу задать новый вопрос если потребуется.

Comment: @z668 эти две опции никак не влияют на результат. анализ кода проверяет немного другое - это проверка кода на распространненые ошибки в момент компиляции. опция отладки на поведение не влияет. сейчас уточню ответ про сборки.